# Add sub elements to a config file (XML) with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, config

i'm getting crazy. I need to modify this XML file in powershell

```xml
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="attr1" indentsize="attr2">
    <listeners>
      <add name="attr1" type="attr2" initializeData="attr3" />
      <remove name="Default" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
  <switches>
    <add name="attr1" value="attr2" /> 
  </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

i need to add a new element after the "remove" one: i tried to use the following code

```powershell
$fileXML = 'C:\Users\XXXX\file.config'
$contentXML = New-Object XML
$contentXML.Load($fileXML)
$elementXML = $contentXML.SelectSingleNode("//listeners")
$childElementsXML = $contentXML.CreateElement("set")
$elementXML.AppendChild($childElementsXML)
$contentXML.DocumentElement.AppendChild($elementXML)
$contentXML.Save($fileXML)
```

but it's moving the element "listeners" at the same level of "trace". What am i doing wrong?

```xml
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="attr1" indentsize="attr2">
  </trace>
  <switches>
    <add name="attr1" value="attr2" />
  </switches>
  <listeners>
    <add name="attr1" type="attr2" initializeData="attr3" />
    <remove name="Default" />
    <set />
  </listeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

thanks in advance for your help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```bsh
$contentXML.DocumentElement.AppendChild($elementXML)
```

`$elementXML` (the `<listeners>` node) is already where it needs to be :)